# jquery global var? how to do this?

Tags: jquery

Okay I have this above my validation:

```
var error = true;
```

Below this all of my validation takes place, for example:

```
/* FIRST NAME VALIDATION */
$("#firstname").change(function () {
    var firstname = $('#firstname').val();
    if (firstname == ""){
        $('#firstname').css({"border-color":"#3399ff"});
        $('#firstname-err').html("You must enter your first name.").removeClass("success_msg").addClass("error_msg");
        error = true;
    }else{
        $('#firstname-err').html("Thank you " + firstname + ", thats perfect!").removeClass("error_msg").addClass("success_msg");;
        $('#firstname').css({"border-color":"#1f6d21"});
        error = false;
    }
});
```

and I have this at the bottom of my validation

```
if(error == true)
{
    $('#btn-join').css({"opacity":"0.4"});
    $('#btn-join').attr("disabled", true);
}
else
{
    $('#btn-join').css({"opacity":"1"});
    $('#btn-join').attr("disabled", false);
}
```

Basically, I want it to run through each one and if they are all false, the submit button becomes enabled.

How do I go about doing this?

I'm fairly new to jQuery so sorry if I didn't make sense.

Comment: Are you saying it doesn't work? (Just `if (error)`, btw.) You might also want to look in to some other ways of specifying your CSS (like a class), or just use a jQuery validation plugin.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do to get a global var in JavaScript or jQuery is to declare it at the broadest scope, then refer to it again (*without the var keyword*).  I usually declare these variables before my jQuery ready() function.  That should let you access the variable throughout the document in your scripts.  Just make sure that you don't re-declare the variable with var or you'll get a localized version of it.

One note on your logic - I am assuming that you're validating more than one field.  Since any of these fields may set the `error` variable to true, you're going to want to avoid setting it to false on individual validation tests.  Here's what I'd do:

- Declare the `error` variable outside the jQuery code.
- When your validation function starts, initialize `error` to false.
- Run each field's validation test.  If the test fails, mark it
  visually for the user and set `error` to true.  If the test passes,
  don't change the value of `error`.
- Repeat for each field's test.
- When all tests are finished, test the value of `error` to see if all
  the tests passed or if you have an error.  Act accordingly.

I hope that helps.

Comment: in addition: although it's not that nice, you can also make sure that you're variable will be globally declared by not using the `var` keyword. This will automatically declare that variable in global scope.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the change event to the form, then all of your form fields will trigger it. In that function validate all of the data.

That way, whenever any value in the form is changed, the button will be updated with the correct state.

Comment: But then won't you have the button flashing on and off after each successful input? That means someone could easily fill out one input box and then submit the form?

Comment: You are correct that the messages flash after the first input, but how else are you going to verify that they are all filled out without a button or something to trigger the validation on input items that have never been focused or changed? Here is a jsfiddle for you. http://jsfiddle.net/ajLkz/

Comment: I don't think that's a problem - the form would only be able to submit if the whole thing is valid.

Comment: The button its self does **not** flash, it stays off.

Comment: Hi BNL, this seems to work, but it doesn't work if the validation (for example if firstname is in side a firstname change function) - How can I get this to work if each input validation is in a change function?

Comment: Manually trigger the form's change event from your function. http://jsfiddle.net/ajLkz/13/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what your problem is here, or what you're asking.

As far as the scope of the variable is concerned, as long as you declare it before the block of code then it should be in scope in your jquery code.

I can forsee some problems with your method though.

I would initially set `var error = false;`. You don't have any errors before you've started.

Then you don't need to set `error = false;` anywhere in the code. If you do this then you're negating any time you've changed it to `true` before in the script.

Lets say you validate first name and then second name afterwards.

First name has an error so you set `error = true`.

Second name doesn't have an error, so you set `error = false`. This will then confuse you because you've forgotten that there was an error with first name.

Lastly an even better way to do it would be to set `var error = '';`. Then as you go through do: `error += 'You need to fill in your first name.<br />';` or similar. That way when you get to the end instead of seeing if `error === true` you can see if `error != ''`. If that evaluates to true then you can output the error which will be contained in the error variable which will be an amalgamation of all the errors you've encountered throughout the running of the script.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The reason I have error set to true at the top is so that the submit button is disabled on page load. Let me have a shot with your suggestion.

Comment: I see... can't you just set the button to disabled in the HTML if you're going to have it disabled from the offset every time?